# Upper bound the dimension of Quotient Space

Tags: quotient-spaces, dual-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $Y$ be the kernel of a bounded linear functional on $X$, say $M: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Is it possible to upper-bound the dimension of the quotient space $X/Y$. I am new to analysis therefore really not sure on whether this is even a good question to consider. But I am working on a problem where an upper bound on the dimension of $X/Y$ could help.

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't this quotient just be the image of $M$?

Comment: Yes, indeed $M: X/Y \rightarrow Range(M)$ is a linear bijection. I am not sure if this is enough to say that $X/Y$ has same dimension as $Range(M)$.

Comment: It's a standard result that if you have a linear injection $f: E \to F$, then you have $\dim E \leq \dim F$, and that if you have a linear surjection $g : E \to F$ then $\dim E \geq \dim F$. In finite dimensions you can use bases to see this.